# About Security concern by adding registry key in windows 7 Desktop Application

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-7-x64, windows

I have used to add `registry key` in my `windows application` for security purpose. It **works great in XP operating System** But when I install my Application on **Windows 7 OS System(64 Bits)** then after 4-5 days my application doesn't find reg key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`.

My Application again asked to add registry key in system. I don't know how my software's reg key is removed or deleted from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` in Windows 7 OS 64 bits.

To add reg key in C#.Net App, I used below code:

```
// Create an instance of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry key
RegistryKey parentKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
// Open the SOFTWARE registry sub key under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE parent key
  RegistryKey softwareKey = parentKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true);
  // Create a DaveOnC# registry sub key under the SOFTWARE key
  RegistryKey subKey = softwareKey.CreateSubKey("MySoftWareRegKey");
  subKey.SetValue("Name", encryptedMac, RegistryValueKind.String);

     subKey.Close();
     softwareKey.Close();
     parentKey.Close();
```

Again I want to mention that `no error has been generated in application at running time`, But after some days (may be 4-5 Days) `my application couldn't find reg key` in location in Windows 7 64 bit System and forced to me to add it again to execute my application.

So directly my question is how to add Reg Key permanently in Windows 7  OS at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`.

Any suggestions or answers are highly appreciate. Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is related to [registry virtualisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your 32-bit interactive process (registry virtualisation doesn't apply to services or 64-bit processes) probably doesn't have permission to create this registry setting on Windows 7, so the system diverts it to a per-user setting as described in that link. As documented in that link, you can use the Reg.exe command-line utility with the FLAGS option to query the state of the virtualisation flags for any registry key.

I'm not sure why it disappears after a period of time - maybe it's checking under a different user or a different virtualisation policy has been applied? But the real fix is to run the program with admin rights if that's feasible, so that the key can be written properly.

**EDIT**: In response to your comment, [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724072%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the 32-bit equivalent of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software (although 32-bit applications are not aware of this redirection). So this is normal behaviour for a 32-bit program. What tool are you using to check the registry key - I suspect it's not showing the re-direction?

Comment: I had already run my application as admin after that I added reg key and It has permission, too for Read/Write. It was successfully added under location `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`. But after some period of time when I search my reg key then it would be found at location `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`. What is the reason behind it? And How can I resolve this problem and add reg key permanently at location `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`. Please Help!!!

Comment: I am not using any tool to retrieve value, I implemented it in my form with using this code :
` 
    string ds = "";
        
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\" + SubKey);
    
            if (key != null)
            {
                ds = key.GetValue(Name).ToString();
    
            }
          
            return ds;
 `
And one question: Is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` find in every Wondows 7 (32 & 64 Bits) OS with Same path and Name **Wow6432Node** ?